# Number of sequences of length $n \geq 1$ with elements from set $ \{0,1,2,3,4 \} $ such that blocks of $0$s, $2$s and $4$s are of even length.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Question statement:

In a sequence $\langle a_1, ...,a_n \rangle$ a block is every maximal subsequence of same digits. For example, in a sequence $\langle 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4 \rangle$ there are $5$ blocks:

- blocks of $0$s and $4$s, of length $2$,
- block of $2$s of length $4$,
- blocks of $1$s and $3$s, of length $1$.

How many sequences of length $n \geq 1$ with elements from set $ \{0,1,2,3,4  \} $ such that every block of $0$s, $2$s and $4$s is of even length (but a given digit can not appear in the sequence at all) exist? Find the closed-form expression with argument $n$.

---

My proposed solution:

First two elements of sequence:

1. $a_1 = 2$, because we choose one of $2$ digits
2. $a_2 = 7$, because we choose digits from the set: $\{1,3 \}$ and put them in any combination on those $2$ places ($11, 13, 31, 33$) or alternativelly, we choose one of $3$ blocks made of digits from the set: $\{0,2,4 \}$. Those are: $00$s, $22$s and $44$s
3. $a_3 = 2*2*2 + 3*2*2 = 20$ (odd digits only: we choose one of $2$ digits for each one of $3$ places, even digits only: there is no way, since we have $3$ places in our equation, odd digits with even digits: we choose the block of even digits out of $3$ possible, then we place it on first or second place, then for the remaining place we choose one of $2$ odd digits)
4. $a_4 = 2*2*2*2 + 3*3 + 3*2*2 + 2*2*3 + 2*3*2 = 25 + 36 = 61$ (odd digits only: we choose one of $2$ digits for each one of $4$ places, even digits only: we choose $2$ blocks of even digits out of $3$ possible, odd digits with even digits: we choose the block of even digits out of $3$ possible, then we place it on first, second or third place, then for the remaining $2$ placs we choose one of $2$ odd digits).

Generalization for all other elements of sequance:

- if on the last place, $n$, there is $0$, $2$ or $4$, then there had to be $0$, $2$ or $4$ before that (on place $n-1$) and a 'correct sequence' on former places (from $1$ to $n-2$). So we choose one of $3$ pairs of digits ($00, 22, 44$) for places: $n$ and $n-1$ and then copy our choices for former places ($n-2$).
- if on the last place there is $1$ or $3$ there had to be a 'correct sequence' on former places: $[1, n-1]$. So we choose one of $2$ digits ($1, 3$) for $n$ place and copy our choices for former places ($n-1$).

So I came with a recursive formula: $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 3a_{n-2}$. From that I get: $\lambda^2 - 2\lambda - 3 = 0$.

I need to solve that equation, so thats what I do:

$\Delta = 4 - 4 \cdot (-3) = 16$

$\sqrt{\Delta} = 4$

- $\lambda_1 = \frac{2 - 4}{2} = -1$
- $\lambda_2 = \frac{2 + 4}{2} = 3$

From that I know that the closed form solution is equal to: $a_n = a(-1)^n + b(3)^n$ for some parameters $a$ and $b$. To find those, I plug in values of $a_1$ and $a_2$ that I've already found.

- $a_1 = 2 = -a + 3b \iff 2 + a  = 3b \iff b = \frac{2 + a}{3}$
- $a_2 = 7 = a + 9b \iff 7 = a + 9 \left( \frac{2+a}{3} \right) \iff 7 = a + 6 + 3a \iff 4a = 1 \iff a = \frac{1}{4}$

$b = \frac{2 + \frac{1}{4}}{3} = \frac{8 + 1}{12} = \frac{3}{4}$

So, finaly, the closed form solution is equal to:

$a_n = \frac{1}{4}(-1)^n + \frac{3}{4}(3)^n$

I test it for my former foud elements $a_3$ and $a_4$:

- $a_3 = \frac{1}{4}(-1)^3 + \frac{3}{4}(3)^3 = -\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4} \cdot 27 = \frac{80}{4} = 20$
- $a_4 = \frac{1}{4}(-1)^4 + \frac{3}{4}(3)^4 = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4} \cdot 81 = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{243}{4} = \frac{244}{4} = 61$

It looks to be working.

---

Now we can prove that its right using induction.

We have the basis for $a_3$ and $a_4$ already done. Then we assume that formula $a_n = \frac{1}{4}(-1)^n + \frac{3}{4}(3)^n$ works for $n-1$ and for $n$. We need to make the induction step:

- $a_{n-1} = \frac{1}{4}(-1)^{n-1} + \frac{3}{4}(3)^{n-1}$
- $a_{n} = \frac{1}{4}(-1)^{n} + \frac{3}{4}(3)^{n}$

We have:

$$a_{n+1} = 2a_{n} + 3a_{n-1} = 2 \left( \frac{1}{4}(-1)^{n} + \frac{3}{4}(3)^{n} \right) + 3 \left( \frac{1}{4}(-1)^{n-1} + \frac{3}{4}(3)^{n-1} \right) =$$
$$= \frac{2}{4}(-1)^{n} + \frac{6}{4}(3)^{n} + \frac{3}{4}(-1)^{n-1} + \frac{9}{4}(3)^{n-1} =$$
$$= -\frac{2}{4}(-1)^{n-1} + \frac{18}{4}(3)^{n-1} + \frac{3}{4}(-1)^{n-1} + \frac{9}{4}(3)^{n-1} =$$
$$= \frac{1}{4} \cdot 1 (-1)^{n+1} + \frac{3}{4}\cdot 9 (3)^{n-1} =$$
$$= \frac{1}{4}(-1)^{n+1} + \frac{3}{4} (3)^{n+1}$$

And as we see, the formula works fine.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Why do you think the proof "doesn't work" and there is an error?  I don't understand what is happening after the sentence that begins "Additionally".  You just start dumping a bunch of symbols, so it is impossible to follow your reasoning.  Please explain your approach.  What is $\delta$?  What are those equations?  What did you obtain as your final closed-form solution? Did you try testing your recurrence relation on $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ to see if it seems correct for small values of $n$?  If not you should do that.  I encourage you to [edit] your question.

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for help! I edited my original question.

Comment: Please test your recurrence relation on $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ to see if it seems correct for small values of $n$, then test your formula to see if it seems correct for small values of $n$.  We expect you to exhaust all reasonable avenues for you to answer your own question, before asking here.  You should be able to do that and I think it is likely to give you insight into the situation.

Comment: @D.W. I edited the question. I think I did all I could, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers.  If you have found an answer to your own question, please post it under 'Your Answer', rather than changing the question.  Our purpose is to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to future people.  Changing the question in a way that renders existing answers incomprehensible does not help contribute to that goal.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you listed appears to be a correct solution.  You have a simple arithmetic error, that made you draw the wrong conclusion.

$$-\frac14 + \frac34 \cdot 27 = -\frac14 + \frac{81}{4} = \frac{80}{4} = 20.$$

Perhaps you missed the negative sign; $-1+81=80$, not $82$.